# Sum all attribute values inside a list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a class with a several Integer atributes, something like it:

```
public class Test {
    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;
    private Integer c;
    private Integer d;
    private Integer e;
    private Integer f;
    private Integer g;
}
```

So, I get a List of this class with a lot of registers and I have to sum individually all attributes of this list. Then I did something like it:

```
List<Test> tests = testRepository.findAllTest();

Test test = new Test();
for (Test testList: tests) {
    test.setA(test.getA + testList.getA);
    test.setB(test.getB + testList.getB);
    test.setC(test.getC + testList.getC);
    test.setD(test.getD + testList.getD);
    test.setE(test.getE + testList.getE);
    test.setF(test.getF + testList.getF);
    test.setG(test.getG + testList.getG);
}
 return test;
```

This implementation is working fine, but I would like to now if there is a more simple way to do it, cleaning this code and making it simple

Comment: I doubt it is doing fine since you are calling `setA()` on every line :). You could wrap it in a an add method like `void addAttributes(Test other)`

Comment: Use an array with 7 `int` elements, then add them in a loop.

Comment: Joakim Danielson I edited, thanks your observation

Answer (score 2):

I would break this down into a couple sub-problems: adding one Test object to another, and summing up the list.

For the first problem, you could add a method to the Test class that adds two test objects and returns a new Test object that contains the sum.

```
public class Test {
    ...

    public Test add(Test testToAdd){
        Test result = new Test();
        result.setA(a + testToAdd.getA());
        ...
        result.setG(g + testToAdd.getG());
        return result;
    }
}
```

And then you could call that in the summing loop:

```
List<Test> tests = testRepository.findAllTest();
Test testTotal = new Test();
for (Test test: tests) {
    testTotal = testTotal.add(test);
}
```

An added benefit is that it is more immediately clear about what the loops is doing.

Comment: You could also have the add method modify the Test object rather than return a new one, and then in the loop you could just call testTotal.add(test)

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your Test class to include an add method:

```
public class Test {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    //...

    public void add(Test o) {
        this.a += o.getA();
        this.b += o.getB();
        this.c += o.getC();
        //...
    }
    // setters and getters...
}
```

Then your summation function can look like this:

```
public Test summation(Collection<Test> testCollection) {
    Test sum = new Test();
    for(Test test : testCollection) {
        sum.add(test);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To add one more similar approach to already existing answers using `Stream.reduce`:

Add a no-args constructor to your test class, if you didn't already have one:

```
private Test() {
    this(0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
}
```

Add a method addAttributes to your test class

```
public Test addAttributes(Test other){
    this.a += other.a; 
    this.b += other.b; 
    this.c += other.c; 
    this.d += other.d;
    //.... 
    return this;
}
```

Then you can reduce your list by doing:

```
Test result = tests.stream().reduce(new Test(), (t1,t2) -> t1.addAttributes(t2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Write an `add(Test other)` method in your `Test` class:

```
public void add(Test other) {
   this.a += other.getA();
   this.b += other.getB();
   // ...
   this.g += other.getG();
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
Test test = new Test();
List<Test> allTests = testRepository.findAllTest();
allTests.forEach(individualTest -> individualTest.add(test));
return test;
```